# Difference between select() and get() in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there any Difference between get() and select() method when using laravel eloquent model. Which method is faster?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes there is a difference. `select()` is only for defining which columns you want. `get()` is for actually getting the result (> executing the query) and it also allows you to specify columns.

```
DB::table('foo')->select(array('bar'));
```

Will **not execute** anything. You still need `get()` for that

```
DB::table('foo')->select(array('bar'))->get();
```

Now you receive a result with only the `bar` column.
The same can be done this way:

```
DB::table('foo')->get(array('bar'));
```

So *syntax-wise* `get()` alone is faster (meaning shorter) while performance wise you won't notice any difference.

**Another little difference**: with `select()` you can use the list syntax

```
select('foo', 'bar', 'etc', 'whatever')
```

and with `get()` you have to use an array

```
get(array('foo', 'bar', 'etc', 'whatever'))
```