# Is an Eloquent Model the same as a MVC model (in laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I saw this post ([The difference between an Eloquent Model and a Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380624/the-difference-between-an-eloquent-model-and-a-model)) but it doesn't explicitly answer the question for me.

I may not be using the right terminology here...

I understand Eloquent to be "...an ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database..." as it says in the documentation. But is what is not clear to me is difference between these eloquent models, and models as one refers to them in the MVC sense.

Does it sound logical if I was to say that in a particular laravel application

1. there will be many models, some of which are Eloquent models, and some of which are models in the MVC sense.
2. Eloquent models are quite lean and pure classes, allowing interaction with the database layer.
3. MVC models, by comparison may contain all sorts of business rules & logic
4. Both types are easily created by `php artisan make:model` although with an Eloquent model one might want to create the migration at the same time.
5. All models are stored in the same place, unless otherwise organised. It's not as if there is some externally visible location or naming convention to indicate that this is an Eloquent Model, or a MVC model.

...is that about right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are only models. Some of them have extended functionality by using the Object-relational mapping methodology - Eloquent ( one of many ).You can read more about ORM here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

2. They are everything but not lean and pure. They are far blown and use a lot of unnecessary data to create relations between database object in the form of easy to read / use syntax. Example `firstModel->secondModel->thirdModel->somethingSilly();`
3. MVC Models can contain everything as Controller **but** they answer to convention so you should probably read more extensively about MVC and the logic behind it.
4. Pretty much that's the purpose of Artisan. To make everything more simple and easy to use.
5. Yep.

If you need a bit more information I can provide you with answers and url  in the comment below.

Comment: Thanks, that's given me a bit to think about.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your answer to #4. Artisan may make things *faster* but I find trying to understand it's flow and structure is incredibly difficult, (but I'm new to this, so meh).

Comment: On #2, I say they are quite lean, because (if I understand it right) you don't have to do any database stuff. An Eloquent model seems to basically be just validation rules, and returns.

Comment: On #3, I understand the logic of MVC. I found CodeIgniter to be a very nice implementation of that. But what does "MVC Models can contain everything as Controller" mean?

Comment: hmmm #4 - The flow and structure of artisian. It just generates predefined files and code structures with a little bit of functionality. I don't get what you mean by difficult. by #2 Lean is probably not the word you want to use. Yes you have very simplified structure for database usage but it comes with a cost. Those heavy heavy multidimensional arrays and structures and collections and sh*t. We have pretty developed hardware so that you don't think about it but in very strict typed language as c, c++ and directly accessing memory everything matters. And I **suggest** make 1-2 MVC

Comment: Examples in JAVA or C# where OOP and MVC structures are way more clear and intentional. The **real** deal, not the php spaghetti code. #3 No, no, no CI has the worst defined MVC workflow. Never ever start to think in ways of CI. You can put all the logic in the model and totally skip the controller and vise versa ( which is hilarious ). Try Symfony, or again if you have the time and basic knowledge go with C# or JAVA.