# Errors on Laravel pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I need to get specific fields from the database and then paginate the results but I am not sure where to place `->paginate()`.

My code is as below:

```
Upload::where('sponsor_id', Request::segment(2))
        //->paginate(20)
        ->join('users', 'users.id', 'uploads.uploaded_by')
        ->orderBy('uploads.created_at', 'DESC')
        ->get([
            'uploads.filename',
            'users.first_name',
            'users.surname',
            'uploads.errors',
            'uploads.statistics',
            'uploads.created_at',
        ])
```

I'm getting the correct results without paginating but I would like to paginate the results.

Comment: Did you try chaining `paginate()` on  `get()`?

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari, that results in error: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist. The 2 answers below do the trick.

Comment: But, I recommend you to have a look here for better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634790/difference-between-select-and-get-in-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to use select then pass in pagination.

```
Upload::where('sponsor_id', Request::segment(2))           
        ->join('users', 'users.id', 'uploads.uploaded_by')
        ->orderBy('uploads.created_at', 'DESC')
        ->select('uploads.filename','users.first_name','users.surname',
             'uploads.errors',
            'uploads.statistics',
            'uploads.created_at')
        ->pagiate(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`select`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects) method for filtering columns. And then put `paginate` method end of your query. 
Finaly your query will be like this:

```
Upload::where('sponsor_id', Request::segment(2))
    ->join('users', 'users.id', 'uploads.uploaded_by')
    ->orderBy('uploads.created_at', 'DESC')
    ->select(
        'uploads.filename',
        'users.first_name',
        'users.surname',
        'uploads.errors',
        'uploads.statistics',
        'uploads.created_at',
    )
    ->paginate(20);
```